# Creating a matrix of matrix-indices

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix of two-dimensional vectors. Every vector should contain the x/y index (or i,j if you want) of its own position in the matrix.

Basically I want something like this:

[image: matrix with two-dimensional vectors]

I know that I could create this in a for-loop, but is there a simpler way? Matlab has so many useful functions for things like that, it surprised me more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`meshgrid` will get you most of the way there:

```
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(0:2, 0:2)

X =

     0     1     2
     0     1     2
     0     1     2


Y =

     0     0     0
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
```

You generally can't have a "matrix of vectors" in Matlab.  Two other options:

1. Make a "cell array" of vectors.
2. Make a three-dimensional matrix (NxMx2) where the third dimension indexes into X or Y (i.e row or column)

To implement the second option:

```
coords(:,:,1) = X
coords(:,:,2) = Y
```

A followup question: why do you want to do this?

Comment: A helpful feline can do the rest: `cat(3,X,Y);`